# How to fix couchbase "Get error response to rev hotel_4396 -> wrong user"

Tags: java, android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm trying to sync couchbase data

I'm using

`couchbase-server-enterprise:6.0.0`

`couchbase-sync-gateway-enterprise:2.1.2`

I followed the steps in this [sample](http://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/travel-sample/develop/java/)

When I run the application, the following error appears

```
2019-01-24 22:42:43.480 9266-9395/com.couchbase.travelsample E/LiteCore [Sync]: {Push#1} Got error response to rev hotel_12228 2-d0a91262108f924ddbac8666b47161a4088bd5d6 (seq #34287): HTTP 403 'wrong user'
2019-01-24 22:42:43.481 9266-9395/com.couchbase.travelsample E/C4Replicator: documentErrorCallback() handle -> 3346004992, pushing -> true, docID -> hotel_12228, domain -> 1, code -> 26, internalInfo -> 5265, trans -> false
2019-01-24 22:42:43.488 9266-9397/com.couchbase.travelsample E/LiteCore [Sync]: {Push#1} Got error response to rev hotel_4396 2-c5bf05117ab54aa57ed4487e8da82d6fdbcf70f3 (seq #34307): HTTP 403 'wrong user'
2019-01-24 22:42:43.488 9266-9397/com.couchbase.travelsample E/C4Replicator: documentErrorCallback() handle -> 3346004992, pushing -> true, docID -> hotel_4396, domain -> 1, code -> 26, internalInfo -> 5266, trans -> false
2019-01-24 22:42:43.871 9266-9266/com.couchbase.travelsample E/Replication Comp Log: Schedular Completed
```

Say it's wrong in username
But I checked my username and password twice
They were correct

Comment: Please turn on verbose logging in sync gateway along with the bucket info to inspect user(cb key) sync gateway tries to get during authentication
“log”:["…",“bucket”]

Comment: its log the same user  `2019-01-25T11:46:20.587+02:00 [INF] SyncMsg: [1388fc29] #2917: Type:rev Id:hotel_4396 Rev:2-c5bf05117ab54aa57ed4487e8da82d6fdbcf70f3 Sequence:34324  User:travel-sample
2019-01-25T11:46:20.587+02:00 [DBG] SyncMsg+: [1388fc29] #2917: Type:rev Id:hotel_4396 Rev:2-c5bf05117ab54aa57ed4487e8da82d6fdbcf70f3 Sequence:34324  User:travel-sample`